# CSS transition table-row height

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-tables, row-height

I have a CSS table. All the rows are the same height, but when a user clicks on one, the selected row should take up the entire table height and the rest of them should fade away.  I had it working by simply setting `display:none` on all the other rows, but I'd like to do something with transitions.

I've tried setting `max-height` to 100% and then changing it to 0, but it only makes the selected row slightly bigger than the rest while the rest stay where they are.  I've tried changing the `height` from 100% to 0, but with height at 100%, the top row is massive and the rest of them are about 15px tall.

In essence, I'd like to transition between `height:auto` to `height:0`, but that doesn't work.  All it does is snap back and forth without a transition.  Any ideas of how to make that work on a table-row?

Comment: It might require a little javascript.

Comment: Yeah.  That's how I'm changing the properties, but I was hoping to get css to take care of the actual animation/transition.

Answer (score 0):

So a quick Google search revealed [this](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/):

```
.our_content {
    /* Initially we don't want any height, and we want the contents to be hidden */
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Set our transitions up. */
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    transition: max-height 0.8s;
}
.outside_box:hover .our_content {
    /* On hover, set the max-height to something large. In this case there's an obvious limit. */
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

You'll need to change the classes and apply when you click with js. I'm curious about how polished your animations need to be. If they need to be polished, I suggest using a fade and a resize.

```
tr {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 360ms;
}

tr.selected {
    -webkit-animation:
    grow 420ms ease-in-out,
    fadeIn 540ms ease-in;
}
tr.deslection {
  -webkit-animation:
    shrink 420ms ease-in-out,
    fadeOut fadeIn 540ms ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes grow {
  0% {
    max-height: /*initial row height*/;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: /*new row height*/;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    max-height: /*new row height*/;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: /*initial row height*/;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

It sounds like you understand adding and removing classes with js, so I'm not explaining that. Please post some code if you need additional help. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think this will work for table rows or cells - them seem to behave uniquely. I am trying this myself and have yet to find a solution that works.

Comment: Why are you using a table? This is much easier to achieve with divs. Can you post your question and code then respond to this?

Comment: I appreciate the offer but at the moment its a situation where I am tasked only to contribute styling - no control over the markup used on the project :( Not the end of the world if it doesn't transition height however - would just have been a little extra eye candy.